# How to set Python .format() padding at runtime?

Tags: python

I'm new to python and trying to print formatted columns of array items to the screen. I found the *.format()* method which can use fixed-width padding to separate the columns.

```
$ ./format.py 
Num  EmpID Name     Team
1    23    Alex     Sales
2    10    Alan     Admin
```

This works OK until one of the items is longer than expected, or *Num* ends up longer than a single digit, or...:

```
./format.py 
Num  EmpID Name     Team
1    23    Alexandria Sales
2    10    Alan     Quality Assurance
```

What I'd like to do is loop over all the items in *user_list* and find the longest element (*Quality Assurance* in the code below) and tell *.format()* to pad all items based on that length. I haven't stumbled across a way to do this however.

Is there a way to define the *.format()* padding at runtime somehow?

```
    #!/usr/bin/python3

class user (object):
  __slots__ =  "name", "team", "empid"

  def __init__ (self):
    self.name        = None
    self.team        = None
    self.empid       = None

def print_menu (user_list):
   index = 0
   print ("{:<4} {:<5} {:<8} {}".format ("Num", "EmpID", "Name", "Team"))
   for person in user_list:
      index = index + 1
      print ("{:<4} {:<5} {:<8} {}".format (str(index), str(person.empid), person.name, person.team))


users=[]
new_user = user()

new_user.name = "Alexandria"
new_user.team = "Sales"
new_user.empid = "23"
users.append(new_user)

new_user = user()
new_user.name = "Alan"
new_user.team = "Quality Assurance"
new_user.empid = "10"
users.append(new_user)

print_menu (users)
```

Comment: Well you certainly can't add padding to something you've already printed, so you will have to compute how long the longest element in each column is before starting to print them.

Comment: Brilliant idea! how do I instruct .format() to use the longest element?

Comment: you could try `max(len(u.name) for u in user_list)`, this should give you the max length of the names. I would also add some additional space for layout.

Comment: @bracco23 , I have a questionm, cant we achive the same thing using `f` strings?

Comment: @FaraazKurawle Sure, `f"{index:<4} {person.empid:<5} ..."`. The format specifiers are essentially the same, but you still have the problem of precomputing the maximum length.

Comment: @bracco23 , Thank you for your answer, well i guess an answer solves runtime padding, isnt it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutly, the trick is to know that you can nest the brackets `{}` in a format string. You would do this in place of the numbers 4,5,or 8 in a string like `"{:<4} {:<5} {:<8} {}"`

heres a quick example:

```
longestName = 8
someObj = (5,2)
print(f'_{str(someObj):<{longestName}}_')
```

That print results in : `"_(5, 2)  _"`
As you can see it has been padded to some integer we can get beforehand by just iterating over all the items and storing the longest item before printing.

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with f-strings. For example:

```
x = 1
d = 5

print(f'{x:0{d}}')
```

**Output:**

```
00001
```

Comment: Had no idea "f-strings" was a thing. Thanks for your input!